# Modification of database outputs from model and passing to view laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

my RESTapi is outputting following json string

```
{"chat":[{"id":100,"chat_id":38,"created_at":"2016-09-07 08:48:17","updated_at":"2016-09-07 08:48:17","messageContent":"Hi there","sender":"client"},{"id":101,"chat_id":38,"created_at":"2016-09-07 08:48:29","updated_at":"2016-09-07 08:48:29","messageContent":"hello sir","sender":"admin"},{"id":102,"chat_id":38,"created_at":"2016-09-07 09:14:24","updated_at":"2016-09-07 09:14:24","messageContent":"test","sender":"client"},{"id":103,"chat_id":38,"created_at":"2016-09-07 09:16:06","updated_at":"2016-09-07 09:16:06","messageContent":"test","sender":"client"}],"currentChatId":38,"senderName":"Client name"}
```

Notice the sender column. These are all coming from db. Now I am writing an algorithm which checks this and finds the sender name to the view instead of just sender type.

I am having problem regarding this..any suggestion?

Here is the controller function

```
    public function getAllChat(Request $request)
{
    // $chatList = chatMessage::where();
    $clientId = $request->session()->get('userId');

    //current chat id7
    $currentChatId = $request->session()->get('currentChatId');
    //find who sent it admin/client
    $chatMessageList = chatMessage::where('chat_id',$currentChatId)->get();
    //sender
    foreach($chatMessageList as $cht)
    {
        //find out sender
        $sender = $cht->sender;
        if($sender=="client")
        {
            $chtP = chatParticipants::find($currentChatId)->first();
            $clientId = $chtP->client_id;
            //find client name
            $client = Client::find($clientId);
            $ch->sender = $client->name;



        }
        elseif($sender=="admin")
        {
            $chtP = chatParticipants::find($currentChatId)->first();
            $adminId = $chtP->admin_id;
            //find client name
            $admin = Admin::find($clientId);
            $name = $admin->name;
            $ch->sender = $admin->name;
        }
    }

    return response()->json([
        "chat"=> $chatMessageList,
        "currentChatId" => $currentChatId,
        "senderName"=>$name
        ]);
}
```

Error : Creating default object from empty value empty value

Comment: In which line are you getting the error? One of your queries does not return an object, make sure all your calls to find() return an object

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo   $ch->sender = $client->name;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have **$ch** variable defined anywhere - I guess you wanted to use **$cht** variable instead.

Replace

```
$ch->sender = $client->name;
```

with

```
$cht->sender = $client->name;
```

and

```
$ch->sender = $admin->name;
```

with

```
$cht->sender = $admin->name;
```

Comment: Cool :) Could you then mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo. 
$cht->sender=$name;

instead of 
$ch->sender=$name;